# Socket Low Transfer Speed - Win7 .Net4 - CentOSx64 Mono 2.10

Tags: sockets, c#-4.0, mono, client-server, centos

I have created a simple client/server app and it works great (1MB/s which is max speed i set for server to send) when i run in locally or under Lan network. But when i try to run it in one of my Dedicate Server/VPS my download speed become slow.
I am using CentOS on servers and Mono for running it, Mono version is 2.10.2 and CentOs is 64bit version. Created using framework 4.

Speed test:

Local: 1MB

Lan: 1MB

Running server on CentOS: 0~10~20 KB

My connection speed is 2Mb or ~250KB. It will give me full speed some times. But very rare and i cant see why it give my full speed sometimes and sometimes no speed at all or why sometimes only 10KB and other times only 20KB. Also, i am running client part on my Win7 Desktop. Here is code for server and client part:

Server:

```
class Program
{
    private static BackgroundWorker _ListeningWorker;
    private static BackgroundWorker _QWorker;
    private static System.Net.Sockets.Socket _Server;
    private static List<System.Net.Sockets.Socket> ConnectedClients = new List<System.Net.Sockets.Socket>();
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program._ListeningWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
        Program._ListeningWorker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
        Program._ListeningWorker.DoWork += _ListeningWorker_DoWork;
        Program._QWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
        Program._QWorker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
        Program._QWorker.DoWork += _QWorker_DoWork;
        Program.Start();
        while (true)
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("1.0.0.1");
            Console.WriteLine(Program.ConnectedClients.Count.ToString());
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
    public static bool Start()
    {
        if (!Program._ListeningWorker.IsBusy)
        {
            Program._Server = new System.Net.Sockets.Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            IPEndPoint ipLocal = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 8081);
            Program._Server.Bind(ipLocal);
            Program._Server.Listen(10);

            Program._ListeningWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
            Program._QWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
        }

        return true;
    }
    private static void _ListeningWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        while (!Program._ListeningWorker.CancellationPending)
        {
            if (Program._Server.Poll(10, SelectMode.SelectRead))
            {
                lock (ConnectedClients)
                {
                    Program.ConnectedClients.Add(Program._Server.Accept());
                }
            }
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1);
        }
        Program._Server.Close();
    }
    private static void _QWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        byte[] array = new byte[1024];
        Random random = new Random();
        while (!Program._QWorker.CancellationPending)
        {
            if (ConnectedClients.Count > 0)
            {
                System.Net.Sockets.Socket[] st;
                lock (ConnectedClients)
                {
                    st = new System.Net.Sockets.Socket[Program.ConnectedClients.Count];
                    ConnectedClients.CopyTo(st);
                }

                foreach (System.Net.Sockets.Socket ser in st)
                {

                    random.NextBytes(array);
                    try
                    {
                        ser.BeginSend(array, 0, array.Length, SocketFlags.None, (AsyncCallback)delegate(IAsyncResult ar)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                ser.EndSend(ar);
                            }
                            catch (Exception)
                            {
                                iDissconnected(ser);
                            }
                        }, null);
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        iDissconnected(ser);
                    }
                }
            }
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1);
        }
        Program._Server.Close();
    }
    internal static void iDissconnected(System.Net.Sockets.Socket client)
    {
        lock (ConnectedClients)
            for (int i = 0; i < ConnectedClients.Count; i++)
                if (ConnectedClients[i].Equals(client))
                {
                    ConnectedClients.RemoveAt(i);
                    i--;
                }
    }
}
```

Client:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter IP Address: ");
        string Address = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine();
        ushort Port = 8081;
        System.Net.Sockets.Socket Client;
        Client = new System.Net.Sockets.Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        Client.Connect(Address, (int)Port);
        Console.WriteLine("Connected");
        int p = 0;
        int t = Environment.TickCount;
        while (true)
        {
            if (Client.Available > 0)
            {
                byte[] z = new byte[1024];
                int r = Client.Receive(z); ;
                p += r;
            }
            else
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
            }
            if (Environment.TickCount - t >= 1000)
            {
                t = Environment.TickCount;
                Console.WriteLine(Program.FormatFileSizeAsString(p) + " Readed,");
                p = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    public static string FormatFileSizeAsString(int len)
    {
        if (len < 750 && len > 0)
            return "0.0 B ~";
        string[] Suffix = { "B", "KB", "MB", "GB", "TB" };
        int i;
        double dblSByte = len;
        for (i = 0; (int)(len / 1024) > 0; i++, len /= 1024)
            dblSByte = len / 1024.0;
        return String.Format("{0:0.0} {1}", dblSByte, Suffix[i]);
    }
}
```

Thanks all, Please tell me what you think about possible problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was some sort of limitation by ISP per each connection.
Solving was funny. I used to send a HTTP Header before my request and ISP increased my speed because of that.